# Web Service Dynamic Connection String single load approach

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

We have a web service application with the database connection string hard coded in the Web.Config as a temporary measure for development.

I want to move this into an external (encrypted) file but I don't want to have to have to read and decrypt this file on every web service call as there will be speed penalty.

Is there a good approach for reading the connection string on the first call to the service to a global and then subsequent calls to the service can reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make a meassurement of wether this is a real performance issue (otherwise you could be adding unnecessary complexity).

If you are sure that it is a performance issue, you could either store it in a static property and load it once in Global.asax OnApplicationStart, and reference the static property from other classes during runtime. If global.asax is unpreferrable you could wrap the property in a class which fetches the connectionstring from your config file if it is not already initialized.

A more "correct" approach would probably be to use some IOC container like Munq or Funq and pretty much do the same (load it once from web.config during application startup and resolve it at runtime). This would easy your unit testing as well. But if you do not already have one, it might be overkill to introduce it.

However, please note: If you decrypt it and store it in memory, it will obviously be stored in memory in a decrypted way, and thus a memory dump or so would include the non-encryptet connection string. A solution could be to keep the file encrypted in memory and accept the minor overhead of decrypting it. Another solution could be to accept this minor security issue; it would depend on the nature of your app. Security always has a cost :-)

Answer (score 0):

A standard approach would be to put the sensitive data into config file section and [encrypt/decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=encrypt%20web%20config) it there. If you experience performance issues with that consider load balancing and horizontal scaling.

> Is there a good approach for reading the connection string on the
>   first call to the service to a global and then subsequent calls to the
>   service can reference it?

It's valid until the connection object is alive. Once the object is disposed - it's gone and with the next connection CLR will decrypt sensitive data once again. In fact, it is a good practise to dispose the sensitive data as soon as possible. You want to remove it from memory  because it can be easily extracted in a pure unencrypted state, which in turn renders the whole encryption useless.